# Offline installation of nodes with node red API

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-red

I am trying to install nodes in nodered with out internet (offline). I have npm pack file (.tgz) and trying to install use admin method "/nodes" POST (https://nodered.org/docs/api/admin/methods/post/nodes/), but "I am getting module not found error".

I tried few things :

1. I extracted the .tgz file and gave path to package.json of nodes.
2. I tried to give the path of dir where the package.json is present.
3. I didn't extract it and gave path of .tgz file. (I know it will not work according to doc)

can anyone please suggest what I am doing wrong here or any other alternative method ?

Comment: It looks like the doc is missing the example for how to upload a TGZ for a node, we can get that looked at, but offline nodes will also have the problem of dependencies that will need to be installed.

Comment: dependencies is not an issue for us now right now we are focusing on installing any node offline that's all.

Answer (score 1):

The procedure to install a Node would be as follows:

You need to do a POST to /nodes where content type is `multipart/form-data` containing the tgz of the packaged node.

e.g. with curl and adminAuth is not enabled

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:1880/nodes -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F "tarball=@node-red-contrib-gpsd-1.0.3.tgz;type=application/x-compressed-tar;filename=node-red-contrib-gpsd-1.0.3.tgz"
```

Comment: if we need to use admin auth, we can add the bearer token in header right ?

Comment: Yes, you can add the header

Comment: we tried multiple times, but it not seems to be working in our offline system,  the file is uploading but its still trying to install by calling node registry.

Comment: As I said, you will still have the problem of all the node's dependencies that npm will try and pull from the network

Comment: some nodes are installing now and for some nodes i'm getting **{"code":"unexpected_error","message":"Install failed"}** and node installation is failing, can you suggest me how i can resolve that issue. how much size it will support to install offline. For nodes have "contrib" in it, there should be dependancy already there right ?

Comment: No, any node you might install could have any number of dependencies that will not be present on the device already, there is no way to know without examining every node by hand and building it's **FULL** dependency tree. I think the max upload size is 5mb by default, you can change that in `settings.js`. You will do better building docker containers with all the nodes you want and then copying the containers to the offline machine than trying to install things this way as there is no way to push the none Node-RED dependencies cleanly via this route